# Запрос MySQL суммирование + обновление + удаление

Tags: mysql

Приветствую!
Возникла необходимость удалить из таблицы базы данных MySQL повторяющиеся записи. Но перед этим суммировать значения определённой колонки.

Исходный вид таблицы:
[image: исходный вид таблицы]

Нужный результат:
[image: нужный результат]

Логика следующая:

- select a, b, sum(c) from table group by b order by a;
- update table set c=sum(c) where a=1;
- delete from table where b=name and id!=1;

Буду рад помощи)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Используйте временную таблицу для хранения суммированых данных.

Comment: Можно даже не временную таблицу, а просто переписать данные в новую таблицу, первым приведенным запросом, после чего таблицу удалить и новую переименовать в старую. Если же таблицу удалять не хочется, то воспользуйтесь своими 2мя первыми запросами в виде `update table A join (select b, sum(c) new from table group by b) B on A.b=B.b set c=new` после чего удалить дубли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8

Comment: да, думал как вариант просто создать новую таблицу... но думал, может можно сделать более элегантно)

Comment: @Mike спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим образом, главное быстро:

1. Делаем копию таблицы, без данных:
2. Копируем из старой таблицы уникальные записи по нужной колонке:

   ```
   insert into table_copy select * from table group by name;
   ```
3. Обновляем записи новой таблицы:

   ```
   update
       table_copy t1,
       (
           select
               table.a as a,
               table.b,
               sum(table.c) as c
           from
               table
           group by
               b
       ) t2
   set
       t1.c = t2.c
   where
       t1.a = t2.a
   ```

   4. Удаляем старую таблицу, а новую переименовываем.

P.S. Из 74657 записей осталось 55545.

Comment: Эммм .... А зачем update ? можно было сделать сразу `insert into table_copy select a,b,sum(c) from table group by b`

Comment: не знаю) но да, можно и сразу

Comment: а, знаю... реальная таблица отличается от примера, проще и быстрее было сделать: select * from, чем перечислять колонки